# How can I pass an object via params in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but in my inexperience, I'm having trouble sorting that better way out.  I have a link that needs to send and object to controller for processing. It isn't working properly:

views/home/index.html.erb

```
<% search_term = "pizza" %>

<% @tag = Tag.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = ?", search_term ]).first %>

<li> <%= link_to(search_term, {:controller => "restaurants", :action => "index", :search_item => @tag}) %> </li>
```

controllers/restaurants.rb

```
def index
  search_tag = params[:search_item]
  @restaurants = Restaurant.search_by_tag(search_tag)
```

models/restaurant.rb

```
Class Restauarant < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.search_by_tag(search_tag)
  search_condition = search_tag.name
  @tags = Tag.find(:all, :conditions => [" name = ?", search_condition ])  
  @tag = @tags.first     
  @Restaurants = @tag.restaurants
 end

end
```

This causes a NoMethodError in ResataurantsController#index

parameters:

{"searchitem" => "15"}

For some reason, the tag object isn't being passed properly  from the `home/index.html.erb` and is only passing along the Tag-object :id to the restaurants controller. Isn't possible to pass a full object this way. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't pass "an object" via HTTP. Fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: "You can't do that sir!" Wow, what am I thinking..

Comment: ..wait, wouldn't `@restaurant = Restaurant.new(params[:restaurant])` be an example of an 'object' being passed?

Comment: Not at all, that's a bunch of values being passed, then used to create an object. All http passes is strings: anything else is smoke and mirrors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't submit an object through get params like that. Typically, you'll just pass the object's id (which you are already doing), and then do a lookup in the controller:

```
@tag = Tag.find(params[:search_item])
```

It would make more sense to rename the "search_item" param to "tag_id".